# jenkinsci docker install-plugins.sh fails build

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am trying to package the vanilla Jenkins image into Docker using this tutorial: https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkinsfile-runner/blob/master/DOCKER.md
Everything works until one of the last steps where the Dockerfile tries to run `install-plugins.sh` from a `plugins.txt` file that was just copeid into its own directory. This is the error I am getting when running docker build:

```
/usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh: line 148: TEMP_ALREADY_INSTALLED: unbound variable
The command '/bin/sh -c /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh < /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Here is my plugins.txt file:

`pipeline-model-definition:latest`

Just the one line.

I cannot seem to figure out what might fix this issue. I tried using the suggestion from this answer here: https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/issues/348 but the command line spat out the exact same error as above. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That variable was defined in [`plugins.sh`](https://github.com/Mirantis/docker-jenkins/blob/80bec927ed5085f626cd8f76cedf148184a00ce7/plugins.sh#L41-L49) (which is deprecated and supposed to be replaced by `install-plugins.sh`)

```
# the war includes a # of plugins, to make the build efficient filter out
# the plugins so we dont install 2x - there about 17!
if [ -d "$JENKINS_HOME" ]
then
    TEMP_ALREADY_INSTALLED=$JENKINS_HOME/preinstalled.plugins.$$.txt
else
    echo "ERROR $JENKINS_HOME not found"
    exit 1
fi
```

But it is not defined in [`install-plugins.sh`](https://github.com/Mirantis/docker-jenkins/blob/6ddff3246a317856e963ab600f4ec3b9ab6e7117/install-plugins.sh), only used (in [line 155](https://github.com/Mirantis/docker-jenkins/blob/6ddff3246a317856e963ab600f4ec3b9ab6e7117/install-plugins.sh#L155))

Try and set `TEMP_ALREADY_INSTALLED` first, as shown above, before calling `install-plugins.sh`.

Comment: I am a little confused as to where to add this check. This is supposed to be in the `install-plugins.sh` files? Or just RUN before I call `install-plugins.sh`?

Comment: @NicholasPesa Just before should work: the call to the `install-plugin.sh` would then inherit the new environment variable you just set.

Comment: This is in a dockerfile so I have tried to copy a script into the container and run it before the install-plugins.sh is called but still comes out with the same error.

Comment: @NicholasPesa Can you `docker build` a new image, from the initial one, instead of copying a file in a running container?

Comment: OK I was able to get it to run and it fails to find `$JENKINS_HOME` and exits

Comment: @NicholasPesa Probably because the preparation steps for using that Docker image were not fully followed. See https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkinsfile-runner#preparation: you can see `JENKINS_HOME` defined there.

Comment: I may have misunderstood the steps then, but my understanding was that is for using jenkinsfile-runner in the command line and if I wanted to use in a docker container I was to package it up using these instructions: https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkinsfile-runner/blob/master/DOCKER.md. The help is appreciated.